# What can be the SQL query for maximum orders on particular date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have lot of dates under date column and along with them number of orders on that date in other column ,i need latest date with maximum orders.

To make myself more clear needed the greatest date but only that which has maximum purchase orders or in other words ***combined result of purchase orders and dates should be the greatest***.

Comment: Post the SQL that you tried & didnt work.

Comment: `needed the greatest date` means?

Comment: greatest date means any latest date withing a week or even a year but having maximum orders for that date. using max(date) would result into   latest date but may not be with highest orders.

Comment: Post some sample data and expected result from the query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be:

```
select date, max(orders)
from table_name
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
select * from (select * from table order by orders desc, date desc) where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: It should be `order by orders desc, date desc`. Isn't it?

Comment: oh, I forgot that. I added desc with date also.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get the rows with max orders and then get the largest of dates.

```
 select max(dates) max_date 
  from (select dates, 
               dense_rank() over(order by orders desc) dr
          from table_name)
 where dr = 1;
```

Testing:

```
 with table_name(dates, orders) as (
 select '12-FEB-2014', 5 from dual union all
 select '11-FEB-2014', 5 from dual union all
 select '14-FEB-2014', 4 from dual union all
 select '10-FEB-2014', 3 from dual)
 --
 --End of data prep
 --
 select max(dates) max_date 
  from (select dates, 
               dense_rank() over(order by orders desc) dr
          from table_name)
 where dr = 1;
```

Output

```
max_date 
--------
12-FEB-2014
```

Comment: i don't know why someone has given negative but seems to be close to the solution.

Comment: What I suspect from your question is that you want to find the dates that have orders with max value from the whole table and then from that list, the greatest date. If so, then this must work with your table.

Answer (score -1):

select top 1 date 
from table_name
order by date desc

Comment: This is invalid in Oracle, from 12c Oracle has LIMIT but not TOP.